# Add custom ID to select2 container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I got the following code for my select2 dropdown menu. Is it possible to give a custom ID to the select2 select2-container? I need a custom a ID so i can add a certain class to it.

```
<th id="filter_16" class="cell ">
        <select id="input_16" class="select-filter select2-hidden-accessible" name="filter[aa_location_type_code]" data-select2-id="select2-data-input_16" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-11-gj73" style="width: 60px;"></span>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#input_16").select2();
                });
        </script>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () { let element = document.querySelector(".select2-container");
element.id='newIdAddedHere' 
console.log(element)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Check console log for new id</p>
<th id="filter_16" class="cell ">
        <select id="input_16" class="select-filter select2-hidden-accessible" name="filter[aa_location_type_code]" data-select2-id="select2-data-input_16" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select>
        <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-11-gj73" style="width: 60px;"></span>
       
</th>
```

Comment: Do you mean

let element = document.querySelector(".select2-container");
element .id='newId'; ?? 

I tried this, but this does not work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: $(document).ready(function () { let element = document.querySelector(".select2-container");
element.id='newIdAdded' 
console.log(element)
});

Yes, you can see that id has been added inside span which has class select2-container.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add a certain class to the select2-container, you could use select2 containerCssClass

```
$select.select2({
  containerCssClass: 'myContainerCssClass'
});
```

Comment: I tried this allready but this doesn't work in my case, I need to assign a custom id to my container <span>

Comment: You must use the full version of Select2 (select2.full.js) in order to support the containerCssClass option.